# JavaFX FXMLLoader 'Location is Required' in JAR file only

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a working JavaFX application, which runs in Intellij. However, i'm trying to run the application as a Jar file,  but I get a NullPointerException saying the location is required.

I've looked at every thread regarding this issue, but none of the solutions seem to work.

Error message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at systems.biology.laboratory.Main.initialSetup(Main.java:23)
at systems.biology.laboratory.Main.start(Main.java:19)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
Exception running application systems.biology.laboratory.Main
```

Snippet of the directory:

[image]

This is the method i'm using to call the FXMLLoader

```
    private void initialSetup(Stage primaryStage) throws java.io.IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/comparisonViewer.fxml"));
    //Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Peak Viewer");
    scene = new Scene(root, 1500, 850);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);

    //scene.getStylesheets().add("/static/css/bootstrap3.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/static/images/peak.png")));
    primaryStage.show();
    controller = new ViewerController();
    controller.setStage(primaryStage);
}
```

Since it works fine in intellij, but not in the jar. Do I need to specify something else?

Comment: Probably the FXML file is not getting deployed to the jar file. Check the contents of the generated jar, (e.g. with `jar -tf MyJarFile.jar` from the command line).

Comment: Using find to narrow down the list could also help: `jar -tf MyJarFile.jar | find "comparisonViewer.fxml"`

Comment: When I try to run it from the command line, I get `Error: could not find or load main class jar`

Comment: can you display the code of the fxml file

Comment: Fixed it, I didn't have all of the classes packed into the Jar file. For some reason I have 3 modules. APUViewer, APUViewer_main and APUViewer_test. I needed to pack both the viewer and viewer_main 
 compile outputs into the jar.